# Remove specific substrings containing integers in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, split

For a small project, I am trying to convert a chess gameplay string to a **list** of chess moves. 
The given string may look like as follows: `s="1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Nc3 d6 4. Bc4 h6 5. d3 Be7 6. Be3 Nc6"`.

Now I wonder what is the **most efficient** way to get rid of the integer denoting in what move-pair we are in the game (e.g. `"1."`), but not the integers indicating to what field coordinate a chess piece has moved (e.g. `"e4"`).

My current approach is as follows:

```
s = s.replace('.', '').split(" ")
s = [e for e in s if not e.isdigit()]
```

In case I would not want to convert to a list, but simply remove the specific parts as indicated above, how would I do that efficiently? Could I maybe use a regular expression from `re` for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `endswith` to check for substrings ending with `.`.

```py
s="1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Nc3 d6 4. Bc4 h6 5. d3 Be7 6. Be3 Nc6"

s = " ".join([substr for substr in s.split() if not substr.endswith('.')])
```

Output:
`'e4 e5 Nf3 Nf6 Nc3 d6 Bc4 h6 d3 Be7 Be3 Nc6'`

Comment: I like this answer. I would not be able to tell you if it's more efficient but since it avoids `re.module` it could be? Kudos =)

Comment: I totally forgot about this approach, exploiting the fact that every move-pair separator ends with a `"."`. This works!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `re.split` for that, following way:

```
import re
s = "1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Nc3 d6 4. Bc4 h6 5. d3 Be7 6. Be3 Nc6"
moves = re.split(r'\s*\d+\.\s*', s)
print(moves)
```

Output:

```
['', 'e4 e5', 'Nf3 Nf6', 'Nc3 d6', 'Bc4 h6', 'd3 Be7', 'Be3 Nc6']
```

Note that I used so called raw-string (or r-string), so I do not have to escape `\`, I used pattern which might be read as:

- 0 or more whitespaces
- 1 or more digits (0-9)
- `.` (this need to be escaped, as `.` has special meaning in patterns)
- 0 or more whitespaces

If you prefer interactive explains, you might paste that pattern into [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).
Note that there is empty `str` at begin of moves, but it might be easily removed using list slicing (i.e. `moves = moves[1:]`)